# Из словаря получить значение и передать его в формулу

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть два словаря. Один с полным ФИО:

```
a = {
  'Иванов Иван Иванович': 12,
  'Петров Петр Петрович': 34
}
```

А другой с инициалами:

```
b = {
  'Иванов И. И.': 12,
  'Петров П. П.': 34
}
```

ФИО в словарях и их значения абсолютно одинаковые. Есть строка с ФИО:

```
c = 'Иванов Иван Иванович', 'Петров П. П.', 'Сидоров Сидр Сидрович'
```

И есть формула:
^3...здесь должен быть номер, присвоенный для ФИО...^A...здесь фамилия...^B...инициалы с точками, через пробел. Вот так эта формула выглядит:

```
^312^AИванов^BИ. И.
```

Мне нужно получить из словаря значения и вставить его в формулу для каждого ФИО. Если Содорова нет в словарях, он будет без цифр. Ожидаемый результат:

```
^312^AИванов^BИ. И.
^334^AПетров^BП. П.
^AСидоров^BС. С.
```

Мне в голову пришло только такая неудобная функция:

```
def get_code():
  av = list(c)
  word = 'Иванов Иван Иванович'
  if word in av:
    return '^312^AИванов^BИ. И.'


d = get_code()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как полностью автоматизировать этот процесс? Заранее благодарна за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = {
  'Иванов Иван Иванович': 12,
  'Петров Петр Петрович': 34
}
b = {
  'Иванов И. И.': 12,
  'Петров П. П.': 34
}

c = 'Иванов Иван Иванович', 'Петров П. П.', 'Сидоров Сидр Сидрович'

for i in c:
    full_name = i.split(' ', 1) if '.' in i else i.split(' ')
    if '.' in i and i in b.keys():
        print(f'^3{b[i]}^A{full_name[0]}^B{full_name[1]}')
    elif i in a.keys():
        print(f'^3{a[i]}^A{full_name[0]}^B{full_name[1][0]}. {full_name[2][0]}.')
    else:
        if '.' in i:
            print(f'^A{full_name[0]}^B{full_name[1]}')
        else:
            print(f'^A{full_name[0]}^B{full_name[1][0]}. {full_name[2][0]}.')
```

Comment: благодарю Вас за ответ. Все сработало. Спасибо большое!!!